# How to design a Text Widget that wraps automatically in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to design a text widget that wraps automatically, and it uses an ellipsis when the text length exceeds the maximum.

The following code can achieve a similar effect.

```dart
Container(
  color: Colors.red,
  child: Text(
    'DENTIFICATIONDENTIFICATIONDENTIFICATIONDENTIFICATIONDENTIFICATIONDENTIFICATIONDENTIFICATIONDENTIFICATIONDENTIFICATIONDENTIFICATIONDENTIFICATIONDENTIFICATIONDENTIFICATIONDENTIFICATIONDENTIFICATIONDENTIFICATIONDENTIFICATIONDENTIFICATIONDENTIFICATIONDENTIFICATION',
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    maxLines: 6,
  ),
),
```

[image]

But it must specify `maxLines`, I don't want this, I need the widget to automatically set the `maxLines` based on the size of parent.

How can I improve the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  String longText = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum";
  double size = 100, fontSize = 16; 

  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: SizedBox(
        height: size,
        child: Text(
          longText,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: fontSize, height: 1),
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          maxLines: size ~/ fontSize,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: But I don't know the height of the parent widget, it will change according to the screen. Is there any way to get it dynamically?

Comment: That's why I asked you who is the parent of your `Text`, and yes you can change it dynamically using `LayoutBuilder`

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove `maxLines` from your code, and your parent widget will handle it accordingly assuming the fact the constraints passed to `Text` are bounded, for instance in this example, I used `SizedBox` with `height: 100`, and output is exactly what you want:

**Edit:**

```
SizedBox(
  height: 100,
  child: Text(
    'DENTIFICATIOND...DENTIFICATIOND...DENTIFICATIOND...DENTIFICATIOND...DENTIFICATIOND...DENTIFICATIOND...DENTIFICATIOND...DENTIFICATIOND...DENTIFICATIOND...DENTIFICATIOND...',
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    maxLines: 1000, // you can freely use any value here
  ),
)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I need Text to wrap automatically instead of manually specifying `\n`.

Comment: I used `\n` just to show you how it would look like if your text exceeds 6 lines you have chosen.

Comment: If don't use `\n`, the text will only be displayed as one line.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it is still not what I want, maybe I didn't say it clearly. The ellipsis is automatically generated by the text, not manually. Use ellipsis instead of excess text when the text exceeds the maximum height of the parent control

Comment: OK, I understand, can you tell me what's the parent of `Text`, can I solve it using `SizedBox`, and if you can share a similar screenshot of what you are trying to get, it will help

Comment: Can be any Widget with `Child` properties, like `Container` and `Sizedbox` are fine. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are some known issues with Text wrapping, specially with the ellipsis if you don't specify the maxLines: [Flexible text overflow ellipsis (softWrap false)](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26006)

But, you could do something like this to determine the maxLines according to the parent widget:

```
SizedBox(
  height: 40.0,
  child: LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
      double fontSize = 16.0;
      return Text(
        "DENTIFICATIONDDENTIFICATIONDDENTIFICATIONDDENTIFICATIONDDENTIFICATIONDDENTIFICATIONDDENTIFICATIONDDENTIFICATIONDDENTIFICATIONDDENTIFICATIONDDENTIFICATIONDDENTIFICATIONDDENTIFICATIONDDENTIFICATIONDDENTIFICATIOND",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: fontSize, height: 1.0),
        maxLines: constraints.maxHeight ~/ fontSize,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      );
    },
  )
```

If you know the height of the parent, you could do something like this:

```
double fontSize = 16.0;
double height = 40.0;

SizedBox(
  height: height,
  child: Text(
    "DENTIFICATIONDDENTIFICATIONDDENTIFICATIONDDENTIFICATIONDDENTIFICATIONDDENTIFICATIONDDENTIFICATIONDDENTIFICATIONDDENTIFICATIONDDENTIFICATIONDDENTIFICATIONDDENTIFICATIONDDENTIFICATIONDDENTIFICATIONDDENTIFICATIOND",
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: fontSize, height: 1.0),
    maxLines: parentHeight ~/ fontSize,
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  )
```